# FullCalendar pop up div on dayClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have little problem with FullCalendar dayClick. Is this possible to show my window (div with my css style) to add new event in calendar?

HTML

```
 <div class="Calendar">
    </div>
    <div class="dayClickWindow">
    </div>`
```

CSS

```
  .dayClickWindow
    {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background-color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-250px;
    margin-left:-250px;
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
}
```

JQ

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.Calendar').fullCalendar({   

             dayClick: function (data, event, view) {
           $(this).show('.dayClickWindow');
        }           
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to call `show` on the element you want to show. Change `$(this).show('.dayClickWindow');` to `$('.dayClickWindow').show();`

Demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.Calendar').fullCalendar({

    dayClick: function(data, event, view) {
      $('.dayClickWindow').show();
     }
  });

});
```

```css
.dayClickWindow {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.css">

<div class="Calendar"></div>
<div class="dayClickWindow"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!